# Sql syntax error when bulk inserting with mysql node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm using the `mysql` node module.

My query is:

```
insert into myTableA (fk_1, fk_2)
values (
    (select id from myTableB where name = ?),
    (select id from myTableC where name = ?)
)
```

My method call looks like:

```
db.query(q, [values], (err) => { ... })
```

Each item in `values` is an array whose items are respectively the names in `myTableB` and `myTableC`.  As shown above, I made sure to wrap `values` in another array.

The error I get is:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...`

Help please...

EDIT 1:

The values I am trying to insert look like the following:

```
var values = [
    [name00, name01],
    [name10, name11],
    [name20, name21],
    ...
]
```

EDIT 2:

Here's to clarify my confusion... Basically, I am looking for a way that would allow me to use the `INSERT INTO` query to combine the following 2 queries:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col_1, col_2, col_3) VALUES ?
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO MyTableA (col_1, col_2, col_3) VALUES (
    (select id from MyTableB where name=?),
    (select id from MyTableC where name=?),
    ?
)
```

The query I am looking for would let me pass a `values` variable in the following form:

```
var values = [
    [row_0_col_1, row_0_col_2, row_0_col_3], 
    [row_1_col_1, row_1_col_2, row_1_col_3], 
    [row_2_col_1, row_2_col_2, row_2_col_3], 
    ...
]
```

Comment: can you post the full error message?

Comment: that's the error passed into the callback, u mean the stack trace?

Comment: The error message appears to be truncated. You need to try this query in a MySQL client and get the full error message.

Comment: There's nothing bulk about this INSERT, by the way. It must insert exactly one row.

Comment: Can the B and C tables be related via a join?

Comment: Your edit does not reflect your actual query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, they're not related, only tableA contains 2 foreign keys respectively from B and C

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, I think I'm understanding my confusion...

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQL `Join` feature, to insert the selected values from multiple tables.

An example for your reference:

```
INSERT INTO Table (aID, bID) 
     SELECT a.ID, B.ID 
     FROM A, B 
     WHERE A.Name='Me'
     AND B.Class='Math';
```

Answer (score 0):

`myTableA` appears to be a many-to-many table, and you're trying to populate the rows to be foreign keys references to `myTableB` and `myTableC`.

With the `INSERT ... VALUES` syntax, you can specify rows of data values, but each row must be specified.  Like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTableA (fk_1, fk_2) VALUES
  ('name00', 'name01');
  ('name10', 'name11');
  ('name20', 'name21');
```

Each row is independent and self-contained. If you use subqueries, each subquery must return a single value (this is called a *scalar subquery*). You can't use subqueries that return multiple values.

You can also use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax, so instead of listing rows one by one, the INSERT just uses the rows returned by a SELECT statement.

```
INSERT INTO myTableA (fk_1, fk_2)
  SELECT b.id, c.id
  FROM myTableB JOIN myTableC ON (...);
```

But you would have to provide some join expression to describe how to match values from the two respective tables in the join.

This would require inventing the many-to-many relationship out of thin air.

As for the syntax error returned by node, the error you included in your post above is truncated where you typed `...`. This isn't a complete error message. The query you posted is obviously edited (I suppose your table names are not `myTableA`, `myTableB`, etc.). You're asking for help but you have provided neither the real query you executed, nor the real error message. Given that, there's no way for anyone on Stack Overflow to guess at the cause of the error, or any fix for it.